# How to know if all slice elements are equal, and if so, return a reference to the first one?

Tags: algorithm, generics, vector, rust, slice

Given any slice, for example:

```
let words = &["one", "one", "one", "two"];
```

How to know if all elements are the same?

Even further, if all elements are the same, how to return a reference to the first one?

Essentially, I'm trying to write a function like:

```
fn are_all_elements_equal<T>(elems: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    // ... ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `.all`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all

First, if the slice is empty, just return `None`.

Then grab yourself an iterator over the rest of the slice, and use the `.all` function to check that the element equals the first element that you just grabbed. If that returns true, return your `Some(first_element)`

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a nice use case for subslice patterns:

```
pub fn are_all_elements_equal<T: PartialEq>(elems: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    match elems {
        [head, tail @ ..] => tail.iter().all(|x| x == head).then(|| head),
        [] => None,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to the answers already posted, you can also make it generic over anything that can be iterated:

```
pub fn iter_all_eq<T: PartialEq>(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Option<T> {
    let mut iter = iter.into_iter();
    let first = iter.next()?;
    iter.all(|elem| elem == first).then(|| first)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", iter_all_eq(&[1, 1, 1]));
    println!("{:?}", iter_all_eq(&[1, 2, 1]));
    println!("{:?}", iter_all_eq(&["abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"]));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=2f1d892757ada29775f490b9090c0039)

Comment: @user4815162342 I wasn't aware `then` was stabilized, I assumed both were to be stabilized at the same time, thanks!

Comment: Weird, I know...

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to do this is using `tuple_windows` from the `itertools` crate:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

pub fn are_all_elements_equal<T: Eq>(elems: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    elems.iter().tuple_windows().all(|(a, b)| a == b).then(|| &elems[0])
}
```

Note that this will panic on an empty slice. To handle the empty slice, you need to explicitly return `None` if `elems.is_empty()`.

Comment: No need for an extra crate; just use `windows(2)` and `|a| a[0] == a[1]`

Comment: @Herohtar That works too. I find the tuple version a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to do using the available built-in functions:

```rust
fn check_all<T: Eq>(items: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    match items.is_empty() {
        true => None,
        false => items.windows(2).all(|a| a[0] == a[1]).then(|| &items[0])
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a1b8382ef21f823d4d32877aa711bc6)

- `.windows(2)` gives you an iterator containing overlapping pairs of elements.
- `.all(|a| a[0] == a[1])` compares the two elements from each window
- `.then(|| &items[0])` returns an `Option` containing a reference to the first element if the previous `.all()` returns `true`, otherwise it returns `None`
- The `match items.is_empty()` is required because `.all()` will also return `true` if the slice is empty, which will result in a panic at `items[0]`

Note that since the comparison used in `.all()` could result in the same value being compared to itself, you need to constrain `T` to `Eq`, [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55130202/574531).